# Can I automatically generate Select queries on Visual Studio similar to what SQL server management studio does?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ssms

I had SQL server management studio on my computer and I used to explore my company's database using it. When building queries it was very easy to right click on a table and 'select top 1000' rows. I would take that code then and modify it. This will save me time typing all field names for example.

Now I have MS Visual Studio and I can't install the Server Management Express. I can explore the database and I can right click on a table and view the records. However, I am not able to generate the select query automatically. How can I create these queries automatically and is there a way to visually design my sql query?

Answer (score 1):

On Visual Studio, if you go tools -> Server Explorer and add a DB Connection, then you can mimic the management studio option to generate sql from db objects...